# Netsuite - Permissions for Approve/Reject Inventory County

Tags: count, permissions, netsuite, inventory

Supply Chain is wanting to restrict who can Approve/Reject the Inventory Count.
I have adjusted the Count Inventory Permission.  but even on 'View' the Approve/Reject buttons are still appearing.

Is there a separate permission for this?

Or a way to hide the buttons through a workflow?

Or would I need to do it through Script? ([netsuite-freak blog](https://netsuite-freak.blogspot.com/2019/06/how-to-hide-buttons-in-netsuite-page.html))

[Screenshot of Netsuite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWE4P.png)

---

- Have tried changing the Count Inventory Permission.
- Have tried setting up a workflow but not finding the count inventory as an object.
- Looked at doing a script but hoping to find a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this was a transaction form.
Two possible solutions found:

1. Make a custom form without the Approve/Reject Buttons.
2. Use workflow to hide the buttons based on role.  I went this route, but would probably go with the first one if doing this again.

regards,